# Sort array of strings by number of vowels using Shell sort

Tags: c

The problem says to sort array of n strings by the number of vowels in each strings. the compiler gives no errors, but when i input 3 words ("apple", "me", "why"), expected output should be:

apple
me
why

but for some reason it prints out

amwhy
mwhy
why

can someone spot the mistakes i made in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int samoglasnik(char *rijec)
{
int br=0;
int n=strlen(rijec);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    char c=*rijec+i;
    if( c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u')
        br++;
}
return br;
}

void ShellSort(char *niz,int n)
{
int i,j,h;
for(h=n/2; h>0; h/=2)
{
    for(i=h; i<n; i++)
    {
        char *x=&niz[i];
        for(j=i; j>=h &&(samoglasnik(x)>samoglasnik(&niz[i])); j-=h)
            niz[j]=niz[j-h];
        strcpy(&niz[j],x);
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int i,n;
char *niz;
do
{
    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
}
while(n<1);
niz=(char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("%d. rijec: ",i+1);
    scanf("%s",niz+i);
}
ShellSort(niz,n);
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%s\n",niz+i);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is sorting an array of `char`.   Code needs to sort an array of _strings_.  Much re-work needed.

Comment: how do i make it an array of strings? Do i need to put char **niz?

Comment: Too much re-work need to fit in a comment.  `char **niz` is a good start.

Comment: Thank you for your response